# GoLang time zone conversion

Tags: go, time

I am looking to display a time in a specific format for a particular country. My current code:

```
now := time.Now()
ogTime := time.Date(2022, 8, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, now.Location())
loc, _ := time.LoadLocation("Asia/Singapore")
convertedTime := ogTime.In(loc)
fmt.Println(convertedTime)
```

This prints out `2022-08-01 08:00:00 +0800 +08`

Is there a way to display `2022-07-31T16:00:00Z?` Is it possible to remove the time offset and instead just have a Z? I have tried `ogTime.Format(RFC3339)` as well as something like `ogTime.Format("2006-01-02 T15:04:05Z")`, but neither work.

Answer (score 0):

`fmt.Println` is using the `Stringer()`-implementation of `time.Time` to print the value as a string, which determines the formatting for you.
To set the format yourself, use `time.Time.Format()`;

```golang
now := time.Now()
fmt.Println(now.Format(`2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00`))
```

A "Z" in the output without an offset means the time is in UTC. If you do not want to print the timezone, omit it from the format;
`fmt.Println(convertedTime.Format("2006-01-02T15:04:05"))`

> 2022-08-01T08:00:00

If you want to print in UTC convert the timezone before printing; `fmt.Println(convertedTime.UTC().Format("2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00"))`

> 2022-08-01T00:00:00Z

Printing a "Z" while the time is not in UTC would require you to concatenate it yourself, but would be silly;
`fmt.Println(convertedTime.Format("2006-01-02T15:04:05") + "Z")`

> 2022-08-01T08:00:00Z

If you want to provide local time and print it in UTC, provide your timezone when parsing the date

```golang
loc, _ := time.LoadLocation("Asia/Singapore")
ogTime := time.Date(2022, 8, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, loc)
fmt.Println(ogTime.UTC().Format("2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00"))
```

> 2022-07-31T16:00:00Z